# Java NIO Selector doesn't work when not using localhost

Tags: java, network-programming, port, ip-address, nio

I've been working on a program that uses networking with Java that uses the NIO Selector following [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio-selector) and for some reason when I try to test the program with my friends (that are far away in another network) it doesn't work, 
even though when I try to test it myself on only my computer it works perfectly.

 Here is the relevant code for the question:

**Class EchoServer (a Thread):**

```
private Selector selector;
private ServerSocketChannel serverSocket;
private boolean stop = false;
private List<String> pendingStrings;

public EchoServer() throws IOException {
    // Get selector
    this.selector = Selector.open();
    System.out.println("Selector open: " + selector.isOpen());
    // Get server socket channel and register with selector
    this.serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    InetSocketAddress hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress("", NetworkingSettings.PORT);
    serverSocket.bind(hostAddress);
    serverSocket.configur eBlocking(false);
    int ops = serverSocket.validOps();
    SelectionKey selectKy = serverSocket.register(selector, ops, null);
    this.pendingStrings = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (!stop) {
        try {
            update();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void update() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Waiting for select...");
    int noOfKeys = selector.select();

    System.out.println("Number of selected keys: " + noOfKeys);

    Set selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
    Iterator iter = selectedKeys.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {

        SelectionKey ky = (SelectionKey) iter.next();
        if (ky.isAcceptable()) {
            acceptClient();
        }
        else if (ky.isReadable()) {
            readDataFromClient(ky);
        }
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

**Class EchoClient:**

```
private SocketChannel client;
private InetSocketAddress hostAddress;
private boolean connected;

public EchoClient(String ip) {
    this.hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress(ip, NetworkingSettings.PORT);
    connected = false;
}

public void connect() throws IOException {
    if (!connected) {
        client = SocketChannel.open(hostAddress);
        connected = true;
    }
}

public void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException {
    try {
        byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(messageBytes);
        client.write(buffer);
        buffer.clear();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        cleanUp();
    }
}
```

Now, it seems that the problem is in the server because I can't even connect to the server when my friend runs it (and I am the client).
I suspect the source of the problem are those lines in **EchoServer**:

```
InetSocketAddress hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress("", NetworkingSettings.PORT);
serverSocket.bind(hostAddress);
```

But I can't seem to figure out what is it.

**Important Note:**`NetworkingSettings.PORT` is 80, I know it's a port used for http and maybe that is the problem, but I really want to avoid needing to use port forwarding and firewall settings.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the `InetSocketAddress` the `ServerSocketChannel` binds to. To allow connections on both localhost and remote network interfaces, you need to bind to the wildcard address. This is done by using the `InetSocketAddress` [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html#InetSocketAddress-int-) that only takes a port number:

```
InetSocketAddress hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress(NetworkingSettings.PORT);
```

Comment: Ok so on localhost this does work, but if I want to test the program with my friend, what IP adress should I give him to try and contact me? the one in sites like [this](http://checkip.amazonaws.com) or another adress?

Comment: Yes, this address, or the corresponding IP address, should work.

Comment: thank you and sorry for the delay, but what if I have two computers running a server like that under the same network? (all on the same router) @Lolo